# Builder pattern. Initialization of duplicate parameters?

Tags: java, builder-pattern

Suppose I have a car builder with parameters such as model, color and speed:

```
 public class Car {

    private String model;
    private int color;
    private int speed;

    public Car(String model, int color, int speed) {
        this.model = model;
        this.color = color;
        this.speed = speed;
    }

    //..Getters

    public static class Builder {
        private String model;
        private int color;
        private int speed;

        public Builder model(String model) {
            this.model = model;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder color(int color) {
            this.color = color;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder speed(int speed) {
            this.speed = speed;
            return this;
        }

        public Car build() {
            return new Car(model, color, speed);
        }
    }
}
```

And I build cars like this:

```
    Car car1 = new Car.Builder()
            .model("Audi")
            .color(Color.RED.getRGB())
            .speed(200)
            .build();
    Car car2 = new Car.Builder()
            .model("Audi")
            .color(Color.RED.getRGB())
            .speed(350)
            .build();
    Car car3 = new Car.Builder()
            .model("Audi")
            .color(Color.RED.getRGB())
            .speed(175)
            .build();
```

As you can see, I have parameters that have to be constantly duplicated. I would like to be able to build new cars based on some existing blanks like this:

```
    Car car1 = new Car.Builder()
            .initFrom(redAudi)
            .speed(200)
            .build();
    Car car2 = new Car.Builder()
            .initFrom(redAudi)
            .speed(350)
            .build();
    Car car3 = new Car.Builder()
            .initFrom(redAudi)
            .speed(175)
            .build();
}
```

Is there any template that provides for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the answers! I decided to go for @tquadrat's solution, but expand on it a bit. I decided to add an interface for the classes that initialize the builders.

Car.java

```
public class Car {

private final String model;
private final int color;
private final int speed;

public Car(String model, int color, int speed) {
    this.model = model;
    this.color = color;
    this.speed = speed;
}

//..Getters

public static class Builder {
    private String model;
    private int color;
    private int speed;

    public Builder initFrom(@NotNull CarBuilderInitializer initializer) {
        Builder builder = initializer.initBuilder(this);
        this.model = builder.getModel();
        this.color = builder.getColor();
        this.speed = builder.getSpeed();
        return this;
    }

    public Builder model(String model) {
        this.model = model;
        return this;
    }

    public Builder color(int color) {
        this.color = color;
        return this;
    }

    public Builder speed(int speed) {
        this.speed = speed;
        return this;
    }

    public Car build() {
        return new Car(model, color, speed);
    }
}}
```

CarBuilderInitializer.java

```
    public interface CarBuilderInitializer {
    Car.Builder initBuilder(Car.Builder builder);
}
```

YourCustomBuilderCar.java

```
 public class YourCustomBuilderCar implements CarBuilderInitializer {
    @Override
    public  initBuilder(@NotNull Car.Builder builder) {
        return builder
                .model("Audi");
                .color(Color.RED);
    }
}
```

Client code:
Car car1 = new Car.Builder()
.initFrom(new YourCustomBuilderCar())
.speed(200)
.build();

Answer (score 1):

This is a common problem. Essentially, you need to expose a `asBuilder()`. This instance method obtains a **builder that is initialized with the values of a passed instance**.

```java
Car existingCar = Car.builder()......build() ;

//new car with same props as existing but the speed
Car existingCarButFaster = existingCar.asBuilder()
                           .speed(existingCar.speed * 2)
                           .build();
```

The implementation of `asBuilder()` should be straightforward.

Also, you seem to be generating a lot of boilerplate. If hooking up the codebase with a code generator is not a problem for you, you can use the `Lombok` library that is used by a vast majority of projects.

```java
    /**
     * If true, generate an instance method to obtain a builder that is initialized with the values of this instance
     * Legal only if {@code @Builder} is used on a constructor, on the type itself, or on a static method that returns
     * an instance of the declaring type.
     * 
     * @return Whether to generate a {@code toBuilder()} method.
     */
    boolean toBuilder() default false;
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a method `initFrom(Car)` to your `Builder` class, that calls all getters from the given `Car` instance and initialises its parameters with the return values. Later invocations of the `Builder`'s methods may overwrite these values with the then correct values.

As next you can introduce a `TemplateCar` class as a new parent class to `Car` that allows to be build with an incomplete parameter set, and that has its own `Builder` (of course, then you need to change the above mentioned method to `initFrom(TemplateCar)`).

Is this what you meant when asking for a "Template"?